# How to insert an item with an incremental value on an attribute in dynamodb

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I'd like to achieve the self incremental feature `like mysql` in `Dynamodb`. After some search, I can only use `updateItem` with an update expression like `{ ":inc": {N: "1"} }`. But it only works for updating an existing item. What I want to achieve is to increase a `version` field by 1 whenever we insert a new item on dynamodb.

Is there a buildin feature in dynamodb to achieve this?

Comment: Unfortunately, no

Answer (score 0):

DynamoDB does not have an auto incrementing count feature, you'll have to implement that yourself.

You could handle this in a transaction, where you insert a new item into DDB and then increment the `version` field by 1.  This approach has the side effect of making sure the version only increases if the `PutItem` operation succeeds.  This is useful when you include a `ConditionExpression` in the `PutItem` call to enforce any other business logic.  If the condition fails, the `version` will not be incremented.

You could go one step further and implement a strategy known as Optomistic Locking.  You would read the `version` field before calling `updateItem`.  In the call to `updateItem`, you would use a `conditionExpression` to ensure the number is what you expect.  If another process updated the version, it will fail the condition check and your `updateItem` will fail. You could try the operation again until you get the outcome you expect.

More info about Optimistic Locking:  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBMapper.OptimisticLocking.html

Comment: How can I ensure that the version is not duplicate if there are many concurrent requests come to the dynamodb table?

Comment: I've updated my comment to include a mention of Optimistic Locking using a version number.